# Error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" R

Tags: r

Hei,
I know there are some threads concerning this error, but none of it was answering my question so far, so I thought I'd give it a try. 
I have a dataframe which looks basically like this:

[image]

now I want to fill the column "prev.temp" with the temperature for the same Transect, same year, same quarter LAST year. I skip 2008 because it's the first year (so there is no data from last year) and then I tell R:

```
weather_data$prev.temp <- NA
num.2008 <- nrow(weather_data[weather_data$year==2008,])
for (i in 1:(nrow(weather_data)-num.2008)){
  Year <- weather_data$year[i+num.2008]-1
  trans.id <- weather_data$transect_id[i+num.2008]
  quarter <- weather_data$Quarter[i+num.2008]
  weather_data$prev.temp[i+num.2008] <- weather_data$LST[weather_data$transect_id==trans.id&weather_data$year==Year&weather_data$Quarter==quarter]}
```

But all I get is the warning

```
    > warnings()
Warnmeldungen:
1: In weather_data$prev.temp[i + num.2008] <- weather_data$LST[weather_data$transect_id ==  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In weather_data$prev.temp[i + num.2008] <- weather_data$LST[weather_data$transect_id ==  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In weather_data$prev.temp[i + num.2008] <- weather_data$LST[weather_data$transect_id ==  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In weather_data$prev.temp[i + num.2008] <- weather_data$LST[weather_data$transect_id ==  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In weather_data$prev.temp[i + num.2008] <- weather_data$LST[weather_data$transect_id ==  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

and so on for all the seventhousandandsomething lines in the dataframe. Somebody has an idea why? Hope that's not a stupid question, I'm quite new to R...

Thanks in advance!

Edit: a few lines from my dataset (saved as .csv)

"transect_id","year","day","month","LST","precipitation","Quarter","SumPre","average.temp"
"TR001",2008,1,1,11.47578335,0,1,83.298453932,13.9583943181648
"TR002",2008,1,1,11.47576523,0,1,83.298453932,13.8530953324835
"TR003",2008,1,1,11.49407959,0,1,83.298453932,13.9139920434176
"TR004",2008,1,1,13.2079916,0,1,86.926050666,14.5018122427143
"TR006",2008,1,1,10.91125584,0,1,90.573905345,13.0206362548352
"TR007",2008,1,1,6.603372097,0,1,77.737346644,10.3549168582747
"TR009",2008,1,1,13.25433731,0,1,33.859304729,14.9906256856923
"TR010",2008,1,1,13.29336548,0,1,29.724921671,15.8152628050659
"TR011",2008,1,1,12.42789459,0,1,42.512791991,14.1881363365165
"TR012",2008,1,1,10.8834753,0,1,92.753992081,13.8890411936044
"TR013",2008,1,1,10.96796608,0,1,92.753992081,13.9739660012857
"TR014",2008,1,1,10.92393589,0,1,92.753992081,13.9506789353297
"TR016",2008,1,1,10.54233265,0,1,34.741512,12.172537263967
"TR018",2008,1,1,10.43720245,0,1,34.741512,12.022837968989

...

"TR016",2013,365,12,10.23799419,0,4,50.94453413,17.3295336755543
"TR018",2013,365,12,9.642765999,0,4,50.94453413,17.2109681291522
"TR019",2013,365,12,12.99611282,0,4,128.850266687,19.7414660293043
"TR020",2013,365,12,17.03261375,9.768366814,4,376.689895288,23.1223101931522
"TR023",2013,365,12,12.33310318,0,4,136.517908337,20.1139735760435
"TR025",2013,365,12,12.97974873,0,4,74.026901609,20.4519523951522
"TR027",2013,365,12,11.9024229,0,4,139.080408216,20.105034704
"TR029",2013,365,12,13.14897919,0,4,123.187800423,20.2958238021087
"TR030",2013,365,12,11.91250134,0,4,139.080408216,20.0771734509239
"TR031",2013,365,12,11.69286346,0,4,139.080408216,20.0171743888696
"TR032",2013,365,12,11.47259903,0,4,139.080408216,20.0680306065326
"TR033",2013,365,12,11.97963524,0,4,117.062066789,18.3602539717283
"TR034",2013,365,12,14.35598278,0,4,119.927000758,20.1186091068696
"TR035",2013,365,12,10.59048462,2.074222326,4,238.580411904,18.9340195089891
"TR037",2013,365,12,12.20473003,13.27494144,4,299.027472969,19.9794068390978
"TR038",2013,365,12,11.80709839,0,4,133.453267087,19.8448736253152
"TR039",2013,365,12,13.96679783,0,4,48.515721084,21.041108784413
"TR040",2013,365,12,9.902122498,0,4,50.94453413,17.425598701913
"TR041",2013,365,12,10.84326458,0,4,49.502096769,17.157990155663
"TR042",2013,365,12,NA,5.120532513,4,113.003856957,NA
"TR044",2013,365,12,13.19787312,0,4,120.363720062,19.4256780770978
"TR045",2013,365,12,11.66844082,6.284669876,4,395.10155391,18.9535037953587
"TR050",2013,365,12,13.73744583,19.49760818,4,585.042889358,21.1455532992391
"TR051",2013,365,12,13.7811594,19.49760818,4,585.042889358,21.2266603652174
"TR052",2013,365,12,14.04342079,5.446793079,4,42.28728497,20.9827080707283
"TR053",2013,365,12,12.27605724,0,4,82.855937481,19.324892184163
"TR054",2013,365,12,13.81909752,0,4,114.275216343,20.4377782650978

The first and last lines. Sorry, if you can't tell without the dataset, then I don't mean to waste your time!

Comment: Questions about code not working are off-topic for SO unless they include a reproducible example, so you should update your question to include a dataset (of reduced size, since yours has thousands of rows) that causes these warnings when you run the code you've provided.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. You should not use a `for` loop for this, but without some toy data we can't really provide good alternatives. Anyway, the reason for the error is always the same: the two sides of the assignment have different length (as the error message tells you).

Comment: I tried to give you a few lines from my dataset, but if you'd need the whole, I can't give you. Sorry, then don't waste your time, if it's not really possible. But why (in general) not a for loop?

Comment: Using `dplyr`, you could do `new_weather_data <- weather_data %>% group_by(transect_id) %>% mutate(prev.temp = lag(average.temp, 365))`. The 365 there assumes that your data include all days and you want the temp from exactly one year earlier. If you wanted to do it by date, it'd get more complicated.

Comment: That works so perfectly well, I'm amazed! And it's so much less complicated too ;-) Thanks a thousand times!